# How to cut a hole in a mesh like this without using boolean

Tags: topology

I have this mesh [image]

I need 3 identical holes in front face. How to do this keeping good topology?

I tried to use boolean modifier, but there is terrible topology at the end and I need to apply subsurf modifier before applying boolean

P.S. I'm also used subsurf modifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want big holes it can be something like that (needs one more edge though). Delete the face, create 8 vertex circle, duplicate 2 times, fill the gaps with some <kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Should I do it with the knife tool or what? Thanks for the answer tho

Comment: create one circle with 8 vertices, duplicate, fill the gaps with some F

Answer (score 1):

One idea:

[image]

Try to get three even square faces.

[image]

Subdivide one face 2-3 times.

[image]

Select the inner faces.

[image]

Activate the LoopTools Addon. Right click your selection and choose circle.

[image]

Delete faces. I hope that helps!